# Need help downloading zip with PHP for NSIS Inetc plugin

Tags: php, download, zip, nsis

So I've been trying to get the Inetc plugin for NSIS to download the zip file mp3splitter20.zip from the following address http://www.hjhappel.de/dlmonitor/download.php?t=d&i=2 but I'm having no luck. I tried the Nsisdl plugin earlier and got the file to begin downloading but I kept getting the following error

> download failed: server did not specify content length

I read it would be a better idea to use Inetc, as it allows for use of HTTP1.1. I tried my best to understand the documentation at the [NSIS inetc wiki page here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in), but I'm at a loss as to how I'm supposed to incorporate the required PHP commands through the HEADER to download my zip file. Now when I try to use the header I get the following error:

> Download Failed: Connection Error

which leads me to believe I'm making a very simple error.

A nudge to some examples or the appropriate NSIS PHP documentation would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance and Cheers

Here is the section of the code that I'm trying to get working.

```
!define file_name "mp3splitter20.zip"
!define file_size "294KB"

Section "F7immersion"
   SetOutPath $INSTDIR
   ;these files must be in the main folder
   inetc::get /HEADER 'Content-type: application/zip' 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'${file_name}.'"' "Content-length: ${file_size}"  "http://www.hjhappel.de/dlmonitor/download.php?t=d&i=2" "$INSTDIR\mp3splitter20.zip" /END
   Pop $R0 ;Get the return value
   StrCmp $R0 "success" +3
   MessageBox MB_OK "Download failed: $R0"
   Quit
   nsisunz::Unzip "$INSTDIR\mp3splitter20.zip" "$INSTDIR"
   Pop $R0
   StrCmp $R0 "success" +2
   DetailPrint "$R0" ;print error message to log
   File /r *.ahk
   File /r *.txt
   File /r *.nsi
   File /r *.exe
   File /r *.ico
   File /r *.ini
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be sending those headers in a request, the server will send those in the reply. (See [List of HTTP header fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields))

To download a file from a "normal" server all you need is `inetc::get "http://example.com/somefile.xyz" "$instdir\thefile.xyz" /END`

Comment: Thank @Anders , I'm making progress. Now when I try to download, the download begins and I see the two progress bars, but I get an error with no information, simply `Download Failed: OK` which is the default for a failed download.

Comment: INetC returns "OK" on success, not "success" (Not sure why it does not use the same string as nsisdl)

Comment: Haha. That was it. Thanks. I just changed the string 'success' to 'OK' and it's working fine now